# Why am I getting "Bad Connection"?

Tags: go

I am using the "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" library.

The db instances are set up same DBMS server, just divide instance.

And I make transaction and send query, insert data into table, table name is same but instance is different.
For example instance name is aaa, table name is atest, instance name is bbb, table name is atest.

But when it commits, return err "driver: bad connection".

I can't find answer why it return the message.

sample source

```
tx, err := DBc.Begin()
if err != nil {
    Lprintf(1, "[ERR ] Begin : %s\n", err)
    return tx, nil, err
}

// instance is aaa
query := "INSERT INTO atest"
rows, err := tx.Query(query)
if err != nil {
    Lprintf(1, "[ERR ] Query : %s\n", err)
    return tx, rows, err
}

defer rows.Close()
defer tx.Rollback()

if rows.NextResultSet() && rows.Next() {
    if err := rows.Scan(&userIndex); err != nil {
        lprintf(1, "[ERR ] %s second return scan error : %s\n", procName, err)
    }
}

//  this is api function - instance is bbb, and insert into atest
ret, _ := FuncApiCallRequest("PUT", "https://aaa.test.com", "json", &param)
if ret == 1 {
}

err = tx.Commit()
if err != nil {
    ### error - driver: bad connection
}
```

Comment: `driver: bad connection` looks like a problem with connecting to the db itself? Are you sure you have checked errors where you actually connect to the db?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @poWar Thank you for replying message, Yes db is connected and error is checked after call tx.Commit() .

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thank you for replying message, I will check link.

Comment: Is this issue resolved ? @user2491067